# Angular 15 file upload into laravel 10 $request->file('image') return null

Tags: angular, laravel, file-upload, httpclient

Im trying to upload a image from angular

```
onImageCahnge(event: any): void {
    if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
      const file = event.target.files[0];
      this.herosliderForm.patchValue({
        imageSource: file
      });
    }
  }
```

on submit

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('image', this.herosliderForm.get('image')?.value)

this.herosliderService.update(this.herosliderForm.value.id, formData).subscribe({
  next: (response: any) => {
    console.log(response)
  },
  error: (response: any) =>{
    console.log(response); //TODO
  }
})
```

In the function herosliderService.update()

```
update(id: number, data:  FormData):  Observable<Object>{

    data.forEach( (value: any ) => {
      console.log('update, value) //DEBUG

    })

    let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.userService.getAccessToken()}`
    })

    return this.http.post(environment.apiUrl+'v1/herosliders/'+id, data, { headers: headers })
  }
```

But on the laravel server i get 422 (Unprocessable Content)
message => ['The image field must be a file of type: png, jpg, jpeg.']

so I debuged and I see when I code

```
$request->file('image')
```

i got null, but when I watch inside the PHP var $_FILES i got the image blob. So always gonna get that requires an image, but never is in laravel, I dont know what happened or what to do.

(I also tried adding or removing "Content-Type" in Headers, converting to blob but nothing)

Comment: try swapping image references: `formData.append('image', this.herosliderForm.get('imageSource')?.value)`, it's wrong now, it has to correspond to `$request->file('image')`

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add acceptance to your headers to receive the file as required format:
if pdf => 'Accept', 'application/pdf'
if image => 'Accept', 'image/jpg'

Comment: I just tried but didnt work, still i have error 422 :'(

Comment: The message it returns: 
['The image field must be a file of type: png, jpg, jpeg.']
What type of file it is? Is the file by any chance as PNG, JPG or JPEG. Sometimes uppercase files can cause problem as not being recognized!

Answer (score 0):

About this error, I debugged today, and I got 2 errors.

1. My angular and Laravel cache.
2. The code `$request->file('image')` doesn't work on `response()->json()` so, always return null when I was testing.

Also before this i checked if my Apache config was `file_uploads=On` and it was.